# not going to other page while clicking a button through javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I have a problem in writing a jsp. My scenario is when i click a button (which is in the table cell) the page must go to register.jsp in right frame(there are two frames and this button is also in second frame)
I am not able to get it. Please help me.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    function addRow(tableID) { 
        var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
        var rowCount = table.rows.length;
        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);


        var cell4 = row.insertCell(4);
        var element4 = document.createElement("input");
        element4.type = "button";
        element4.value = "Edit";    
        element4.name = "e5[]";
        element4.attachEvent('onclick',Hi);
        cell4.appendChild(element4);

    }

    function Hi()
    {

        document.write('<a target="two" href="register.jsp"/>');


    }
    </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you mean:

```
function Hi() {
  window.location.href = "register.jsp";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
document.getElementById('iframe_id').src = 'register.jsp';
```

PS: You should stop using iframes / frames, they are slowly but surely becoming deprecated. And even if they weren't, it's not a very user friendly solution.

PS2: To the other people who answered: he wants to change the location of an iFrame, not the whole page.